# Child theme enqueueing style.min.css not style.css

Tags: templates, child-theme

Theme Name : StrapPress with bootstrap 4.2

I created child theme using Child Theme Configurator.
It created `functions.php` and `style.css`,
but when I applied new styles in the `style.css` it did not change anything.
Then I went through the source code, there was no `style.css` from child theme directory, but there was `style.min.css`.

Currently I changed the `style.css` name to `style.min.css` and it works, but this is not the correct way.

Because it gives me another problem like I have one custom template. but it is not showing up in edit page. When I change the `style.min.css` to `style.css` it is showing up.

I also created child theme manually. The same problem.

Comment: do you have `SCRIPT_DEBUG` constant set anywhere? if true it will attempt to load `.min` of some resources, possibly this is what is happening.

Comment: @majick No. i searched the whole theme.